# Binding Table row textbox and Id, Then save to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Assessment view that has a table of student populated form a particular class. The table has two separate textboxes added to each of the row

This is the Assessment view

```
@model  _5._3_EduAdmin.Models.AssessmentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Assessment", "Student", FormMethod.Post)){


@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClassId)

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 offset2">
        <div class="box">

            <div class="box-content nopadding">
                <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-condensed table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#
                            </th>
                            <th>Students Name</th>
                            <th>Assessment Score</th>
                            <th>Exam Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewData["Students"] as IEnumerable<_1._2._0_Core.Domain._2._10_Domain.StudentManagement._10._1_StudentModels.Student>)
                        {
                            int serial = 0;
                            serial++;
                            <tr>
                                <td>@serial</td>
                                <td>@item.Surname, @item.FirstName @item.MiddleName</td>
                                <td class="span3">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestAggregate, new {@class = "input-medium"})
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="span3">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExamsScore, new {@class = "input-medium"})
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Now I want bind each student id to the textbox in that row so that when posting to database I will be able to assign that particular score to the student id in the database, am posting it to another model call Result that has Student id Reference in it.

How do I make it work that way in my controller and then plug it in to my service that saves it to database.

this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assessment(AssessmentViewModel model)
    {


            var students = _studentService.getNurStudentbyClass(model.ClassId).Select(x => x.Id);

            foreach (var id in students)
            {
                if (model.ExamsScore == 0)
                {
                    if (model.TestAggregate != 0)
                    {
                        model.ExamsScore = 0;
                        model.TotalScore = model.TestAggregate + model.ExamsScore; 
                        _recordService.CreateResult(model.TestAggregate,model.ExamsScore,model.ExamsScore,model.Grade,model.TermId,model.SubjectId,id,model.SessionId);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

this is what I came up with... Please am not sure if am on the right track here please any Ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following approach:

Using jquery ajax in mvc. collect the values using id of input parameter and send it by ajax depending upon respective Id.

```
 Change your html as below:  
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".Update").click(function(){
                    var allValues=$(input[name:allValues]);
                    var arrId = [];
                    var arrExamsScore = [];
                    var arrTestAggregate = [];
                                $.each(allValues, function(i, item) { 
                                   arrId.push($(this).val())
                                   arrTestAggregate.push($(this).attr("data-TestAggregate"))
                                   arrExamsScore.push($(this).attr("data-ExamsScore"))
                                });


                    $.ajax({
                            url:"ControllerName/Assessment",
                            data:{"Id":Id.join(","),"ExamsScore":ExamsScore.join(","),"TestAggregate":TestAggregate.join(",")}
                            success:function(result){

                            }
                    });
                }); 
            })  

                @foreach (var item in ViewData["Students"] as IEnumerable<_1._2._0_Core.Domain._2._10_Domain.StudentManagement._10._1_StudentModels.Student>)
                {
                    int serial = 0;
                    serial++;
                    <tr>
                        <td>@serial</td>
                        <td>@item.Surname, @item.FirstName @item.MiddleName</td>
                        <td class="span3">
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestAggregate, new {@class = "input-medium",@id="TestAggregate"+@item.Id})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="span3">
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExamsScore, new {@class = "input-medium",@id="ExamsScore"+@item.Id}) 
                                <input type="hidden" name="allValues" value="@item.Id" data-ExamsScore="@item.ExamsScore" data-TestAggregate="@item.TestAggregate"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
```

Now change your controller first line as follows

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assessment(string Id,string ExamsScore,string TestAggregate) 
    {        /// split here above input values 
        /// convert to int and then process


            var students = _studentService.getNurStudentbyClass(Id).Select(x => x.Id);

            foreach (var id in students)
            {
                if (model.ExamsScore == 0)
                {
                    if (model.TestAggregate != 0)
                    {
                        model.ExamsScore = 0;
                        model.TotalScore = model.TestAggregate + model.ExamsScore; 
                        _recordService.CreateResult(model.TestAggregate,model.ExamsScore,model.ExamsScore,model.Grade,model.TermId,model.SubjectId,id,model.SessionId);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: yea thanks but I don't want to add it up 1 by 1, I want a single button action after input.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes taht also possible. collect all the values first and make list and collect as list and process.

Comment: Can you please add it in your answer please? so i can understand the steps thanks